# I need to utilize the BooleanField on the front end

Tags: python, django

I want the user to use the BooleanField to pick which meals said animal eats (breakfast, lunch, dinner, a combination of these possibly). And if the checkbox is checked I then want it to produce a schedule on screen where you can check off if the animal has eaten said meal that day. The issue is whenever I add my schedule, it will not produce a schedule where I can check off if the animal has eaten. (I know this explanation may sound confusing).

Here are my models for Animal and Schedule:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    """The actual animal, embeded in animaltype"""
    animal_type = models.ForeignKey(AnimalType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.name)>20:
            return self.name[:20] + "..."
        else:
            return self.name

class Schedule(models.Model):
    """Model for animal eating schedule"""
    animal = models.ForeignKey('Animal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    breakfast = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lunch = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dinner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my views for adding a schedule and viewing it(on the animal view):

```
@login_required
def new_schedule(request, animal_id):
    """add a new schedule for the animal"""
    animal = Animal.objects.get(id=animal_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #create 3 different checkboxes for the meals and if they check it, add that meal to their schedule
        form = ScheduleForm()
    else:
        #POST data submitted
        form = ScheduleForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_schedule = form.save(commit=False)
            new_schedule.animal = animal
            new_schedule.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('zoo_animal_feeders:animal', args=[animal_id]))

    context = {'animal':animal, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'zoo_animal_feeders/new_schedule.html', context)

@login_required
def animal(request, animal_id):
    """shows a single animal and the schedule associated"""
    animal = Animal.objects.get(id=animal_id)

    schedule = animal.schedule_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'animal':animal, 'schedule':schedule}
    return render(request, 'zoo_animal_feeders/animal.html', context)
```

Here is my adding schedule template:

```
{% extends "zoo_animal_feeders/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block header %}
  <h2><a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:animal' animal.id %}">{{ animal }}</a></h2>
  <h2>Add new schedule:</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}

  <form action="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:new_schedule' animal.id %}" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    {% buttons %}
      <button name='submit'>add schedule</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

And here is the template where the schedule is supposed to be seen:

```
{% extends 'zoo_animal_feeders/base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>{{ animal }}</h2>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Schedule:</p>
  <p><a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:new_schedule' animal.id %}">add schedule</a></p>
  {% for schedule in schedules %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>
          <small>
            <a href="{% url 'zoo_animal_feeders:edit_schedule' schedule.id %}">edit schedule</a>
          </small>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <!--This is where I need to add the checkboxes that you can check and stay checked until midnight each night-->
        {% if schedule.breakfast == True %}
          {{ schedule.breakfast }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if schedule.lunch == True %}
          {{ schedule.lunch }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if schedule.dinner == True %}
          {{ schedule.dinner }}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% empty %}
    <li>There are no schedules for this animal yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the schedule actually added and make the instance of `schedule.breakfast == True` to produce a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for schedule in schedules %}
```

Change this line to

```
 {% for s in schedule %}
```

You are returning {'schedule':schedule} in the context

Now user s.breakfast etc for each condition

Comment: Also why is the foreign key to animal given in quotes ?    'Animal'?